# Is H2 Database able to make SQL query of the over clause with Aggregate function?

Tags: sql, h2, window-functions

such SQL like

```
SELECT empno, deptno, 
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY deptno) DEPT_COUNT FROM emp WHERE deptno IN (20, 30);
```

is very useful.

I just wonder if in H2, how do we implement the similiar function?
Maybe creating a java procedure will work. But will this function
 be inside the roadmap of H2 database?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no support for windowing functions in H2.

This has been discussed recently in the H2 forum:

http://groups.google.com/group/h2-database/browse_thread/thread/3899106a85851de3#

Comment: That's true, H2 doesn't currently support window functions. So the workaround is: `select empno, deptno, (select count(*) from emp e2 where e2.deptno=e.deptno) dept_count from emp e where deptno in (20, 30);`

Comment: Very nice and rapid answer. I have read the content in the link. In my work, without windowing functions, I have to use subqueries which makes SQL much complex and error prone.